# Pandas: join columns sum some rows and mean others

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
mydic = {'time': {'Type1': 15, 'Type2': 47, 'Type3': 23, 'Type4': 45}, 'count': {'Type1': 26, 'Type2': 39, 'Type3': 34, 'Type4': 67}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydic, orient='index')
df.head()
```

df:

```
        Type4   Type1   Type3   Type2
count   67      26      34      39
time    45      15      23      47
```

I need to join some columns according to a dictionary: sum some rows but calculate average for others. I can do sum() OR mean() but cannot figure out how to do both in one go without creating different data frames for 'count' and 'time'. Help, please?

My code:

```
def merge(df):
    types = {'Type1&2': ['Type1', 'Type2'], 'Type3&4': ['Type3', 'Type4']}
    columns_to_drop = ['Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3', 'Type4']
    for t in types:
#        df[t] = df[types[t]].sum(axis=1)
        df[t] = df[types[t]].mean(axis=1)
    df.drop(columns_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True) # Drop merged columns

merge(df)
df.head()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need select rows by `loc` for `mean` and for `sum`:

```
def merge(df):
    types = {'Type1&2': ['Type1', 'Type2'], 'Type3&4': ['Type3', 'Type4']}
    columns_to_drop = ['Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3', 'Type4']
    for t in types:
        df.loc['count', t] = df.loc['count', types[t]].sum()
        df.loc['time', t] = df.loc['time', types[t]].mean()
    df.drop(columns_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True) # Drop merged columns
    return df

df1 = merge(df)
print (df1)

       Type1&2  Type3&4
count     65.0    101.0
time      31.0     34.0
```

Comment: Right! I tried `loc` but messed it up in this bit `df.loc['count', types[t]]`. Thank you again! Back on track now.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe try this ?

```
d = dict(Type1='Type12', Type2='Type12', Type3='Type34', Type4='Type34')
df1=df.T.groupby(d).agg({'count':'sum','time':'mean'}).T
df1
Out[1004]: 
       Type12  Type34
count      65     101
time       31      34
```